# Cross tab summary fields don't restrict by column

Tags: crystal-reports

so I'm working with Crystal Reports 10 and was looking at the cross tab to try and have a nice and neat table of my information.  I'm trying to make a report where for each item (as a row), the columns will be the different sizes it comes in and the value of that cell will be the quantity.

So something that looks like this:

```
        Small  | Medium | Large
Item 1    1    |  5     | 10
Item 2    5    |  10    | 15
```

Using the cross tab though, the quantity field I have has to be totalled, averaged, etc. so I can't get the specific breakdown for each size in a nice table like that.  Is there any way to tweak the Cross Tab to do this or is there another tool in Crystal Reports that would let me have the quantities per size in that organized fashion?

Thanks for any help you guys can give.

Update:
The cross tab I have tried gives me something that looks like this

```
        Small  | Medium | Large
Item 1    16   |  16    | 16
Item 2    30   |  30    | 30
```

If I put the values in the details section as separate fields, I'm able to get the values to match up properly, but its not the right format.  It comes out like this

```
Item 1 | Small | 1
Item 1 | Medium| 5
Item 1 | Large | 10
```

Comment: Have you tried totaling it? That would still work, even if there's only one record of each size. What does your data source look like?

Comment: What do you mean totalling it?  Right now, using the example above, the quantities for item 1 show up as 16 | 16 | 16 because its got the SUM for each quantity field.

The data source has (among other things obviously), a row that includes the item and a specific size with its quantity.  Each size is saved on a different row with that item and the number of different sizes can vary too so it won't always be just 3 or 4 or w/e.

Comment: I meant using a sum. Would you post the source data? That'll help :)

Comment: And you're using a crosstab now, but you're seeing `item 1 | 16 | 16 | 16`? Craig's solution sounds right to me, so if that matches what you already have your problem might be elsewhere, like joins. I'd suggest seeing if you can generate rows like `Item 1 | Small | 1` to make sure you've gotten the joins correct.

Comment: updated the main post.  Hope it makes some more sense now.

Comment: I'm suggesting as a troubleshooting step that you remove the subreport, and print out the item description, size, and quantity in a detail section. Make sure the data looks like what you're expecting. The cross tab Craig describes should do exactly what you're asking for, which suggests that the problem might lie elsewhere, like an erroneous join.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what else to have you try.

Comment: got it figured out now.  The problem was with my SQL.  The alias names got mixed up when I was copying it into VB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create a Cross-tab
- Add {table.size} to the Columns
- Add {table.item} to the Rows
- Add {table.quantity} to Summarized Fields

Comment: That's what I've tried so far.  The problem is that the quantities are summed together and I end up with the total quantity for each size rather than the right size/quantity pairing.

Comment: Do you have the fields in the CT as I describe in my answer? If so, something unusual is occurring. Could you post a picture of your cross-tab in design mode?